# Debugging Unexpected method call Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and added asset-pipelining to my app.

After a call to a method is done, example method1.

```
def method1
  @locations = Location.name_like(params[:term].to_s) # returns a valid hash of values 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @locations.to_json }
  end
end
```

another method(method2) is being called. As a result I am getting a nil class error.

I checked my logs and it does not show how or why method2 is getting being called. Also I checked if any javascript is calling method2 but there is no javascript for that.

I need help in debugging this situation.

Also I was wondering if asset-pipelining is causing this issue.

Thanks,

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

The assets pipeline is mounted at /assets so I think this is unlikely.

It sounds as though the route for method1 is being captured and sent to method2.

This can happen if a broader route encompassing method1's route is higher up the file.

I would run the rake routes task, and also walk through the route file looking for broad routes the would match method1.